# Suggestion For Data Access Layer with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-4.0, data-access-layer

I want to get you view point about this Question:

I write a Data Access Layer using Entity Framework and generic classes.because using transaction in C# is not very best practice : [Issue with System.Transactions,SqlConnection and Timeout](http://weblogs.asp.net/ryangaraygay/archive/2008/04/14/issue-with-system-transactions-sqlconnection-and-timeout.aspx)

I want to write my select statement using Linq To Entities but other statement such as "INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE,..." in Stored Procedures(because it must be in transaction with some other statements) and call them in Data access layer.

Is it good? Is it inconsistent with tiering?Can anyone demonstrate some articles?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write entire data access layer using Entity Framework. For Transaction you can use EF Context. This will automatically manage transaction for you if there is single database.

```
using(var context = new YourDataContext())
{
   //use context for CRUD operation
   Entity1 entity1 = context.Entities1.Where(e1 => e1.Id == 1);
   entity1.Prop1 = "New Value";  

   context.Entities2.Add(entity2)

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is there any reason you don't want to do Insert/Update/Delete using EF?

Comment: Yes because if I have update stetement with insert statement this two statements does not execute as a transaction

Comment: @Nima : Please look into my update. You can do Update/Insert together inside the context.

Comment: +1 @Amitabh is correct that the update and insert as illustrated would run in a transaction - `context.SaveChanges()` uses an transaction internally - you only need `TransactionScope` etc. if you need a transaction that spans more than one DB context or includes other resources.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write my select statement
>   using Linq To Entities but other
>   statement such as
>   "INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE,..." in Stored
>   Procedures(because it must be in
>   transaction with some other
>   statements) and call them in Data
>   access layer.

You can use a [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx) for this together with EF. This will allow you to add transactions on top of EF that will be honored (an ambient transaction).

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    //your EF query here
    using(var context = new EFContext())
    { } 
}
```

Comment: I am afraid maybe TransactionScope has bugs like this : http://weblogs.asp.net/ryangaraygay/archive/2008/04/14/issue-with-system-transactions-sqlconnection-and-timeout.aspx My system has many transaction that must be transaction

Comment: @Nima: I have used TransactionScope before but have not found any bug. I think u can give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [function imports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx) to execute stored procedures.  You can then obviously wrap all of your transaction logic within those stored procedures.  I love the entity framework but have some of the same concerns that you do.  The function imports are how I have accomplished the majority of my transactional processing and complex logic.

Your code would then look like this (in a simplified fashion)...

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    context.ExecuteProcToRunTransaction("parameter 1", "parameter 2");
}
```